# How to handle master/follower database promotion with makara gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have Rails using Makara to read from a master/follower Postgres database structure. If the master database fails, the Postgres `trigger_file` is set to automatically promote the follower to master and start accepting writes.

Is there a way to configure Makara to automatically recognize the promotion and start treating the follower database as a master? If not, do other gems handle this (either in conjunction with makara or in replacement of it)?